# How to test listener interface is called within Android Unit Tests

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit

I have the following (example) structure within my Android app which I'm trying to write a unit test for:

```
class EventMonitor {
  private IEventListener mEventListener;

  public void setEventListener(IEventListener listener) {
    mEventListener = listener;
  }

  public void doStuff(Object param) {
    // Some logic here
    mEventListener.doStuff1();
    // Some more logic
    if(param == condition) {
      mEventListener.doStuff2();
    }
  }
}
```

I want to ensure that when I pass certain values of `param`, the correct interface methods are called. Can I do this within the standard JUnit framework, or do I *need* to use an external framework? This is a sample of a unit test I'd like:

```
public void testEvent1IsFired() {
  EventMonitor em = new EventMonitor();
  em.setEventListener(new IEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void doStuff1() {
      Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void doStuff2() {
      Assert.assertTrue(false);
    }
  });
  em.doStuff("fireDoStuff1");
}
```

I'm also a beginner in Java, so if this isn't a good pattern for testing purposes I'm willing to change it to something more testable.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here you want to test `EventMonitor.doStuff(param)` and while executing this method you want to make it sure whether the correct methods on `IEventListener` were invoked or not.

So, in order to test `doStuff(param)`, you don't need to have a real implementation of `IEventListener`: what you need is just a mock implementation of `IEventListener` and you have to verify the exact number of method invocations on `IEventListener` while testing `doStuff`. This can be achieved with [Mockito](https://github.com/mockito/mockito) or any other mocking framework.

Here is an example with Mockito:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

public class EventMonitorTest {

    //This will create a mock of IEventListener
    @Mock
    IEventListener eventListener;

    //This will inject the "eventListener" mock into your "EventMonitor" instance.
    @InjectMocks
    EventMonitor eventMonitor = new EventMonitor();

    @Before
    public void initMocks() {
        //This will initialize the annotated mocks
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        eventMonitor.doStuff(param);
        //Here you can verify whether the methods "doStuff1" and "doStuff2" 
        //were executed while calling "eventMonitor.doStuff". 
        //With "times()" method, you can even verify how many times 
        //a particular method was invoked.
        verify(eventListener, times(1)).doStuff1();
        verify(eventListener, times(0)).doStuff2();
    }

}
```

Comment: the most usable solution , but what if doStuff1() needs a certain parameter and i dont care about it content ?